# Trying to get property 'level' of non-object when trying to edit data and showing it in select option

Tags: laravel

I wanted to edit data and show the data in select option.

Heres my controller code:

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

I'm trying like this but getting an error

```
<select class="form-control" name="level" id="level">
                 <option value="{{ $user->level }}"> {{ $user->level }} </option>
                 @foreach ($user as $item)
                 <option value="{{ $item->level }}">{{ $item->level }}</option>
                 @endforeach
       </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

WHat you're trying to do is loop a foreach on a single object, which is not correct.
if you see your controller, **User::findOrFail($id)** does not return a collection of objects, it returns only 1 object, and in your view, you're trying to loop thru that single object